# How to export song from Logic Pro

Tags: macos, logic-pro

I have two tracks that I imported into Logic, mixed those up, and now I want to export the song as a mp4.  How do I do this? everything I try seems to mess up the song.. either pieces are missing, or I'm given all the pieces as separate files, either of which is what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *exporting tracks*, then this is the wrong option. In audio recording terminology, you want to *bounce* the tracks. In the tape recording days, this was the procedure where you took a multi-track composition and "rendered" it to one result track, thus saving space on a tape machine with limited tracks available.

Anyway, you go to *File → Bounce…* (or press `⌘B`).

Then, select your output options.

[image]

This should all be explained in the manual that came with your copy, or the [Logic Pro online support](http://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/9.1.6/en/logicpro/usermanual/#chapter=29&section=0).